# How to set positions and alignment of textfields in Contact Form 7 & Custom Contact Form plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to know how to set positions and alignment of textfields in Contact Form 7 & Custom Contact From plugin in wordpress?

How to set width and height and positions of textfields in wordpress Contact Form 7 & Custom Contact Form Plugin?

Means I want my textfield

width is 300, 
height is 65, 
X position is 350,
Y position is 750,

I am not able to do this in wordpress Contact Form 7 & Custom Contact Form plugin.

Comment: Position the contact form where you want it on the page and then use css to modify the height and width of the textfields.

Comment: how to modify css?  I am doind  in css  input.MyTextArea{ width : 500px;  height: 65px}    And calling in like this [text* name Class: MyTextArea] watermark:"My Field";  but I am not getting any results not a 1 pixel increment on textfield

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the `height:65px`. If you view the source of the form, does the inputbox have `class="MyTextArea"`?

Comment: class have textarea but if I do it in this block all textfileds size are increase I want some textfields size 300px and some 500px, how to do that any idea? Only change particular textfields size and height?

Comment: If you are using chrome, inspect the input box and find a unique value of it and set the width/height of that.

Comment: I am using localhost WAMP

Comment: I am referring to the browser.

Comment: not solve my problem, how to edit and resize particular textfiled in.css?

Comment: Without finding something specific for each input box you won't be able to do it. If you were able to provide a link to the page it would help.